# How do I stop details section extending my page length?

Tags: html, css

I have multiple details section on my page, and each time one is opened it extends my page slightly, though it doesn't return when the details section is closed. I'm almost there with these sections, so I'd rather not change them out now. When I started this site I wanted to avoid using bootstrap as much as possible, but I guess it would have been much easier. Thanks.

```css
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-self: center;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
}

.btn1 {
  width: 18em;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent;
}

.card {
  width: 18em;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em 1em 0;
}

.card img {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 18em;
  height: auto;
}

summary {
  width: 18em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #202020;
  background: #808080;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

.fa.fa-angle-down {
  transition: .15s transform ease-in-out;
}

details[open] .fa.fa-angle-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-.2em);
}

summary:focus {
  outline-style: none;
  background: #404040;
  color: #fef;
}

details {
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 17.55em;
  color: #fef;
  background: #212529;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -.25em 0 -2em;
  border-right: solid 1px #b5b5b5;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #b5b5b5;
}

.contentul li {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="main-container" id="main-container">
  <div class="card" id="card">
    <details>
      <summary id="s1"><img id="img1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503708928676-1cb796a0891e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="ex1">Excavators<br><i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="i1"></i></summary>
      <ul class="contentul">
        <li>180° Wheeled</li>
        <li>360° Wheeled</li>
        <li>360° Tracked</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <details>
      <summary id="s2"><img id="img2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503708928676-1cb796a0891e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="dz1">Dozers<br><i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="i2"></i></summary>
      <ul class="contentul">
        <li>180° Wheeled</li>
        <li>360° Wheeled</li>
        <li>360° Tracked</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <details>
      <summary id="s3"><img id="img3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503708928676-1cb796a0891e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="th1">telehandlers<br><i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="i3"></i></summary>
      <ul class="contentul">
        <li>180° Wheeled</li>
        <li>360° Wheeled</li>
        <li>360° Tracked</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are actually changing the height so naturally the page gets longer. If you want these "sections" to not affect layout you will probably have to position them absolutely.

Comment: Ok will try that, though unsure as to how I would do that using the CSS grid. Will need to research.

Comment: I've tested this code on Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (all on the Mac). In all three cases, the height of the page grows when you expand the details, and in all three cases, the height of the page returns to what it was before when the details section collapses. But there is a problem I can see. In Firefox, there's a disclosure triangle at the top of each image, which twiddles out the details at the bottom, but the details are cut off. In Safari and Chrome, no triangles and details display fully. Do you want a triangle to twiddle the details, or no?

Comment: Thank you, on my local file on chrome that is not the case for me. I have edited the code as I forgot to include the font awesome stylesheet link. The style should be image over summary section, with a twiddle arrow below the summary text. I have the original webkit arrows display set to none, as they were located at the top of the image.